# react-admin TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined

Tags: typeerror, react-admin

I'm trying to show a list of users with react-admin.

CustomerList.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  TextField,
  Datagrid,
  DateInput,
  DateField,
  Filter,
  List,
  EmailField,
  SearchInput,
  SimpleForm,
} from 'react-admin';
import { useMediaQuery, Theme } from '@material-ui/core';

import MobileGrid from './MobileGrid';

const CustomerFilter = (props: any) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <SearchInput source='q' alwaysOn />
    <DateInput source='created_at' />
  </Filter>
);

const CustomerList = (props: any) => {
  const isXsmall = useMediaQuery<Theme>((theme) =>
    theme.breakpoints.down('xs')
  );
  return (
    <List
      {...props}
      filters={<CustomerFilter />}
      sort={{ field: 'created_at', order: 'desc' }}
      perPage={100}
    >
      {isXsmall ? (
        <MobileGrid />
      ) : (
        <SimpleForm>
          <Datagrid optimized rowClick='edit'>
            <TextField source='id' />
            <DateField source='created_at' showTime />
            <DateField source='updated_at' showTime />
            <EmailField source='email' />
            <TextField source='status' />
          </Datagrid>
        </SimpleForm>
      )}
    </List>
  );
};

export default CustomerList;
```

But i have an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined.

```
Something Went Wrong
A client error occurred and your request couldn't be completed.
Détails
TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
at SaveButton (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:134106:25) at div at div at Toolbar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:31314:23) at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Toolbar)) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:41921:31) at Toolbar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:140673:38) at WithWidth(Toolbar) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:37871:90) at form at SimpleFormView (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:139725:21) at FormView (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:108800:19) at ReactFinalForm (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:189371:20) at FormWithRedirect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:108697:18) at SimpleForm at div at Paper (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:20241:23) at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:41921:31) at Card (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:5097:23) at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card)) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:41921:31) at div at div at ListView (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:150222:23) at ListContextProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:96869:18) at List (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:149806:79) at CustomerList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4177:91) at WithPermissions (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:95243:23) at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193616:29) at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193818:29) at ResourceContextProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:103522:21) at ResourceRoutes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:103390:17) at Resource (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:103460:15) at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193616:29) at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193818:29) at RoutesWithLayout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:103566:21) at div at main at div at div at LayoutWithoutTheme (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:147666:24) at WithStyles(LayoutWithoutTheme) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:41921:31) at withRouter(WithStyles(LayoutWithoutTheme)) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193873:37) at Connect(withRouter(WithStyles(LayoutWithoutTheme))) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:190558:75) at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:40623:24) at Layout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:147783:26) at MyLayout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:8952:80) at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193616:29) at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193818:29) at div at CoreAdminRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:103033:87) at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193616:29) at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193818:29) at CoreAdminUI (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:103242:15) at AdminUI at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:193251:30) at ConnectedRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:49787:7) at ConnectedRouterWithContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:49892:25) at Connect(ConnectedRouterWithContext) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:190558:75) at TranslationProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:110397:28) at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:190271:20) at CoreAdminContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:102802:25) at AdminContext at Admin (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:154193:22) at App
```

This is the lastest version of react-admin and all dependencies were updated.

What's wrong with the save button?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: the error came from SaveButton component so might as well share that component as well?

Comment: I think it's that component: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/a2db79a04e3685e484fa171c1b964320ce7f6970/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/SaveButton.tsx

Comment: Same here suddenly on `v3.11.0` on multiple views, might it be a regression ? I suggest you to switch from the RA `SimpleForm` component to the `react-final-form` `Form` component.

Comment: Could be linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65304121/tutorial-throws-context-is-undefined-error-in-savecontext

Comment: FYI an issue has been open on the react-admin github repository https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5691

Comment: FYI this has been fixed in RA `3.11.2` which will be released soon.